# Is there a way to vertically align two div elements with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to center vertically two separate divs within two separate flex containers. Is it possible with any of the flexbox properties to do this or do you have to tinker with the margin/top-bottom-left-right properties until you get it right?

[image]I've included a graphic for what I'm trying to create.

The top row and the bottom row are the divs in their respective flexbox containers.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Hello. You can create two divs which has two child divs. And you can give box style to these child divs. If you use display: flex for the parent divs it will automatically put the child divs side by side. If you share your code I can help you more.